# Where is Packet Delivery Ratio parameter option in OPNET for AODV IN MANETS

Tags: networking, opnet

Im not able to find PDR packet delivery ratio option in Opnet as a parameter for my MANET project using AODV routing protocol. What option should i select for packet delivery ratio option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Packet delivery Ratio in standard MANET model. You have to add a statistic to measure that for it.